# Javascript: How to search multiple arrays for the same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

The idea of this is that it looks at an unspecified number of arrays (held in an array themselves) and it searches each one for similar values. I have given it a try but I can't think of any number of for loops or temporary arrays to hold value to solve my problem.

Examples:

```
[[2,3,5]
 [2,3,5]
 [2,3,7]]
```

This 2D array is an example of what it will be used on and the returned value the code should give is:

```
2,3
```

becasue those numbers appear in all 3 cases, again this will be used on an unspecified number of arrays but since I haven't really done anything with unspecified amounts of things I don't know where to begin.

I am sorry I cannot provide any tried code but I got to constructing some nested for loops and then sat looking at It wondering what to write...

Comment: Yes the solution uses two for loops (one nested inside the other). It's not hard, try to do it, I believe in you :)

Comment: Hint: the first loop (over *i*) iterates the array positions, the second loops (over *j*) checks if every array has the same number in the *i*-th position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `indexOf` you can check if a certain value is present in an array,

so you can filter each value of the first array checking if it's present in all other arrays :

```js
var array=[
 [2,3,5],
 [2,3,5],
 [2,3,7]
];

var res = array[0].filter(function(x){
 return array.every(function(y){
   return y.indexOf(x) >= 0
 })
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.reduce() to achieve this, e.g.:

```
var arrays = [[2,3,5],
              [2,3,5],
              [2,3,7]];

var result = arrays.reduce(function(r, nested, idx, arr) {
    nested.forEach(function(item) {
        r.counts[item] = r.counts[item] ? ++r.counts[item] : 1;
        if (r.counts[item] === arr.length) {
            r.res.push(item);
        }
    });
    return r;
}, {counts:{}, res:[]}).res;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mdArr = [
  [2, 3, 5],
  [2, 3, 5],
  [2, 3, 7]
];


function checkDups(mdArr) {
  var arr = [];

  mdArr.forEach(function(el, i) {
    var arr_temp = el.filter(function(x) {
      var flag = true;
      if (arr.indexOf(x) != -1) return false;
      for (var j = 0; j < mdArr.length; j++)
        if (mdArr[j].indexOf(x) == -1) {
          flag = false;
          break;
        }

      return flag;

    });
    arr = arr.concat(arr_temp);
  });

  return arr;

}

alert(checkDups(mdArr));
```